# 正規表現で数字のあとのコンマのあとにスペースを入れる方法

Tags: 正規表現

お世話になります。
数字のあとのコンマのあとにスペースを入れたいと考えています。
そこで、下記のような正規表現を指定しました。

```
パターン文字列：
(\d+),
検索語の文字列：
\1,
```

しかし、上記のような正規表現の場合、「1,2,3,4,5」のような文字列は問題ありませんが、「1,234」のように位取り点が含まれる文字列では「1, 234」のようになってしまい、少し不都合です。
なにかよい書き方はないでしょうか。
なお、言語はPythonを利用していますが、特にこだわっているわけではないため、これ以外でも結構です。
わかりにくい質問となってしまい恐縮ですが、アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 『「1,2,3,4,5」のような文字列』に3桁の数値が入ると、『「1,234」のように位取り点が含まれる文字列』とまったく区別が付きません。これらが区別できるような条件があるのでしょうか? たとえば、前者には3桁の数値ははいらない、など。

Comment: 確かにおっしゃるとおりでした。手動で書き換えた方が早そうです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

そもそも「位取り用のコンマ」と「区切り用のコンマ」はどのように区別をつける要件でしょうか？
何か条件があるのであれば、その条件を実装すればよいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

「位取り用のコンマ」と「区切り用のコンマ」の判別を目視で行うしかないならば、正規表現置換が可能なテキストエディタで個別に置換するのが手っ取り早いと思います。

位取り用のコンマがほとんどないテキストであれば、下記のサンプルコードのように全置換をしつつ怪しい箇所をリストアップして告知する運用方法も考えられます。

**サンプルコード**

```
import re

src = """ 
1,2,3,4,5
12,345 位取り
,123,456,789
1,23,456 1個目の,は区切り。2個目の,は位取りかもしれない
これも123,4567 位取りではない
1.234 567,890 小数点以下はスペース区切り
""" 
pattern = re.compile(r",(\d+)")

# 置換
result = pattern.subn(r", \1", src)
print(result[0])
print(f"{result[1]}か所置換しました。")

# 位取りカンマ候補の簡易チェック
if(result[1] > 0):
    print("位取りカンマ候補の位置と、**該当テキスト**を表示します。")
for i, l in enumerate(src.splitlines()):
    for m in pattern.finditer(l):
        if len(m.group(1)) == 3:
            print("{}行{}文字目は位取りカンマかも: {}**{}**{}".format(i+1, m.start()+1, l[:m.start()], l[m.start():m.end()], l[m.end():]))
```

**実行結果**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
12, 345 位取り
, 123, 456, 789
1, 23, 456 1個目の,は区切り。2個目の,は位取りかもしれない
これも123, 4567 位取りではない
1.234 567, 890 小数点以下はスペース区切り

12か所置換しました。
3行3文字目は位取りカンマかも: 12**,345** 位取り
4行1文字目は位取りカンマかも: **,123**,456,789
4行5文字目は位取りカンマかも: ,123**,456**,789
4行9文字目は位取りカンマかも: ,123,456**,789**
5行5文字目は位取りカンマかも: 1,23**,456** 1個目の,は区切り。2個目の,は位取りかもしれない
7行10文字目は位取りカンマかも: 1.234 567**,890** 小数点以下はスペース区切り
```

Answer (score 0):

「肯定先読み」と「数字以外」を組み合わせてはどうですか？

```
(\d+)+,(?=\D)
```